# Is package Pandoc already included in Anaconda3?

Tags: anaconda, pandoc

I would like to ask if [Anaconda 2019.10](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section) already includes package [Pandoc 2.9.2](https://pandoc.org/installing.html). The only information I can found is the command to install pandoc from Conda:

[image]

If it's already included in Anaconda 2019.10, then I don'n need to download and install it reparately.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Which OS/platform are you using?

Comment: Hi @AMC, I'm using Windows 10 Pro build 1909.

Comment: I forgot to ask: Why do you need to know if it's included? If it is, then it won't be downloaded, that's all. Or are you really asking how to get Pandoc version 2.9.2?

Comment: @AMC I know it's silly but I don't want to run the command `conda install` if the package is already there.

Comment: Why is that? Even if the package is already installed, you need to `conda install` in order to add it to the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fresh installing Anaconda 3, I found that the package `pandoc` is already included in it and that the version is not 2.9.2 but older.

Comment: _the version is not 2.9.2 but older_ Are you on Windows?

Comment: @AMC yeap,  Windows 10 Pro build 1909.

Comment: Looking at the image in your post, I'm guessing the version is 2.1.3 ?